# Android Studio - Room Persistence Library - Ensuring that the Primary Key a user enters is unique before inserting into the database

Tags: android, database, android-studio, primary-key, android-database

I'm learning how to use the Room Persistence Library in Android Studio, which is basically a layer of abstraction on top of SQLite that makes databasing easier.

In my sample application, I'm allowing the user to enter very basic student information:

[image]

I've created the following three necessary components for the database:

**1. Entity (Student)**

```
package com.aleks.firstdatabaseproject;

import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;

/* This is one entity that will be stored in our database. A Student has a
 * unique ID, a first name, and a last name.
 */

@Entity
public class Student {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @ColumnInfo(name="notes")
    private String notes;

    public Student() { this("", "", "", ""); }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String notes) {
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
        setEmail(email);
        setNotes(notes);
    }

    public void setId(int id){ this.id = id; }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }

    public int getId() { return this.id; }

    public String getFirstName() { return this.firstName; }

    public String getLastName() { return this.lastName; }

    public String getNotes() { return notes; }

    public void setNotes(String notes) { this.notes = notes; }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**2. Data Access Object API**

```
package com.aleks.firstdatabaseproject;

import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Delete;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Insert;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Query;

import com.aleks.firstdatabaseproject.Student;

import java.util.List;

/* A Data Access Object (DAO) provides an abstracted interface that allows
 * a user program to request information from the database. The DAO provides
 * methods for insertion, deletion, and querying in the database.
 */

@Dao
public interface StudentDAO {

    @Insert
    void addStudent(Student student);

    @Delete
    void removeStudent(Student student);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Student")
    List<Student> getAllStudents();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE id IS :studentID")
    Student findStudentByID(int studentID);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE first_name LIKE :first AND last_name LIKE :last")
    List<Student> findStudentByName(String first, String last);
}
```

**3. Database**

```
package com.aleks.firstdatabaseproject;

import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;

import com.aleks.firstdatabaseproject.Student;
import com.aleks.firstdatabaseproject.StudentDAO;

@Database(entities = {Student.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class StudentDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    /* Used by apps to get the data access object from the database */
    public abstract StudentDAO studentDAO();
}
```

For reference, here's the main activity:

**Main Activity**

```
package com.aleks.firstdatabaseproject;

import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static StudentDatabase mDatabase;
    private StudentDAO mStudentDAO;
    private TextView mFirstName;
    private TextView mLastName;
    private TextView mId;
    private TextView mEmail;
    private TextView mNotes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                StudentDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
        mStudentDAO = mDatabase.studentDAO();

        mFirstName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_firstName);
        mLastName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_lastName);
        mId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_id);
        mEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);
        mNotes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_notes);
    }

    /* Uses the information in the app's main fields to build and
     * return a new Student object for use by other methods.
     */
    public Student buildStudentFromFields() {
        String firstName = mFirstName.getText().toString();
        String lastName = mLastName.getText().toString();
        String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
        String notes = mNotes.getText().toString();
        return new Student(firstName, lastName, email, notes);
    }

    /* Called when the user clicks the "ADD" button. Inserts
     * the given Student into the database.
     */
    public void addStudent(View view) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mStudentDAO.addStudent(buildStudentFromFields());
            }
        }).start();
    }

    /* Called when the user clicks the "REMOVE" button. Removes
     * the given Student from the database.
     */
    public void removeStudent(View view) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mStudentDAO.removeStudent(buildStudentFromFields());
            }
        }).start();
    }

    /* Called when the user clicks the "FIND" button. Returns
     * information about the given Student from the database.
     */
    public void findStudent(View view) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Student student = mStudentDAO.findStudentByID(Integer.parseInt(mId.getText().toString()));
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

---

**What I want to do**

You'll notice in the entity class that I've included the annotation `@PrimaryKey(autogenerate = true)`. This designates the `id` field as the primary key of the `Student` table, and the `autogenerate` option forces the database to generate its own primary keys instead of the user consciously remembering to pass in a unique key. But users are prone to error, and they may accidentally hit the `ADD` button twice, for example.

Here's the problem: I want to allow the user to pass in their own custom Student ID like I've shown in the screenshot, but that poses a problem if the user attempts (illegally) to enter the same Student ID twice—the app crashes in that case.

One potential solution is to keep a set/hash table of all IDs the user has entered so far and make sure that what they've entered is unique before trying to `ADD` the Student to the database. But that just takes up more memory than seems necessary (not a lot for such a small app, but it doesn't seem reasonable to store that extra "junk" info).

**Is there any way I can account for duplicate primary keys to prevent the app from crashing when a user accidentally enters the same Student ID twice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to define OnConflictStrategy in your Insert method to handle the error, check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Insert)